# How to set apt options like "Acquire::http::No-Cache=true" in preseed.cfg

Tags: apt, preseed

Something on our company's network is causing some apt updates to fail during an unattended install. We recently discovered that we can fix the apt problem on a previously successful installation using the following options:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=true -o Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth=0
```

Or by putting these options in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80http

```
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
```

However, I still don't know how to modify a preseed.cfg file so that it will use these options for apt. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,